# Is there a way to disable save short cut (ctrl-s) in Firefox 101+?

Tags: firefox, save, disable

Have a requirement on a closed system to disable shortcuts whilst using firefox.  i.e. using ctrl-s to save.  And some others also ctrl-o for example.

Is there anyway to do this?  I've tried googling userchrome.css but having trouble finding anything useful.

version of firefox in use is 101.0.1(64 bit)

Thanks all

Comment: What's the operative system that needs to be closed?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox itself doesn't allow it by itself.
Browser extensions have a limited API and cannot prevent default app shortcuts.

You can use some application at Operative System level to trap the inputs and filter them.

I'm not sure what is the OS you are working on but, on Linux, you can use [`Autokey`](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).
However what app will be effective for your apps depends on the display-server running on your system (e.g. XOrg, Wayland, etc.).